# Print JavaScript date in 'MMM dd, yyyy' format (like 'Oct 17, 2012')

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am getting a date string in ISO format (for example, '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'), but while printing it in my html page I should print it in 'MMM dd, yyyy' format (for example, 'Oct 17, 2012').

What is the simplest way to achieve this without using any library?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many, many questions already on [formatting dates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date), find an answer that suits, write some code and post again if you have issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleDateString()`.

> The toLocaleDateString() method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the date portion of this date.

```js
const date = new Date(),
      dateString = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'});
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: `en-US` provide date in that format.

Comment: It seems backwards to search for a locale that has the right format string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` for this ([in supporting browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_datetimeformat_format)).

You create a formatter with the options you want, in your case, the year should be "numeric", the month "short" and the day "numeric".

You can construct a date object using your ISO8601 string and then pass it to the formatter.

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "numeric" });
const date = new Date("2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z");
formatter.format(date);
// => 'Oct 17, 2012'
```

Alternatively, you could set up an array of month names and use the `getMonth`, `getDay` and `getFullYear` methods of `Date`, like so:

```js
const months = ["Jan", "Feb", ... , "Dec"];
const date = new Date("2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z");
`${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getDay()}, ${date.getFullYear()}`;
// => 'Oct 17, 2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to convert the string to a Date object, then extract the relevant data into a format string if none of the canned formats match (toDateString(), toLocaleString() etc).